# How to change the foreground(Text) color of My ToolKit Data Grid in UWP windows app

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, win-universal-app, windows

I am using My Toolkit Data Grid (you can find here https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid) in my Universal Windows Application. In that I want Grid background as black and Foreground nothing but text in White color. I am able to change the Background color but not able to change the Foreground color.
Please can any one suggest me.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<controls:DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Firstname" 
              Binding="{Binding Firstname}"
              d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=models:Person}" Foreground="White">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ItemTemplate property:

```
<controls:DataGrid.ItemDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid d:DataContext="{Type=models:Person}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding something}"
                       Foregroun="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:DataGrid.ItemDetailsTemplate>
```

Let me know if it work!

Comment: It is to show the details of a specific item. I want just white color for the text displayed in data grid rows.

Comment: Try with <controls:DataGrid.ItemTemplate>
Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<controls:DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="SomeHeader" Binding="{Binding Property}"  >
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="SomeHeader" Foreground="Green" />
    </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</controls:DataGridTextColumn>
```